Loss of keyboard/trackpad events
I have a keyboard and Magic Trackpad 2, plugged into a Cinema Display via USB cables. The monitor's DisplayPort cable is then plugged into a MBP/Mac mini. The issue is that occasionally key presses and trackpad taps don't register. Has anyone else experienced this?
EDIT: The Cinema Display uses a Mini DisplayPort cable, so I'm using an adapter to plug into the USB-C port of the MBP/Mac mini. Maybe that's the issue?

Does the problem also occur if you connect keyboard/trackpad directly to your Mac?

@nohillside No, only when going through the monitor. I added some more info.

Yeah, could be any of the cables and devices used. Unfortunately, the only way to debug this is to replace them one by one.
